# Are there any inexpensive network adapters that will work with ESXi?

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-esxi

I have an ASUS motherboard (P5M2-E/4L) with on-board quad-ethernet (Marvell 88E8056), but ESXi does not see them.

I need 4 ports for my setup.

Would like to stay under $200.00.

Comment: If Zoredache's answer worked for you, it's courtesy to accept that answer to let people know that it did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know most of the equipment we have use Intel Gig nics.  If you want to go really cheap perhaps try out a desktop nic http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833106121

Also see [whitebox ESXi](http://www.vm-help.com//esx40i/esx40_whitebox_HCL.php#NICs) for other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I bought 4 Intel NICs from Newegg for about $100. Worked great!
Zoredache's answer led me to this solution.

Intel EXPI9301CTBLK 10/100/1000Mbps PCI-Express
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833106033

Intel PWLA8391GT 10/100/1000Mbps PCI PRO/1000 GT Desktop
http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833106121R